# Node server Unable to connect the mysql database connect ETIMEDOUT at Connection._handleConnectTimeout

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am unable to connect the mysql database. When I trying to start node server many time it throw database connection error.

Error is :-

```
connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleConnectTimeout
```

Comment: The connection is timing out...

Comment: First: Did you start the mySQL server?

Comment: Second: Can you show how you configured the database in your node.js application?

Comment: I have increase the connection time and its work. But thanks your suggetion

Answer (score 1):

Create a file mysql_yourname with:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "pass",
  database: "databaase"
});
conn.connect(function(err) {  
    if(err) throw "There is no connection to the mysql server..." + err.message;  
    console.info("Connected!");  
}); 
exports.conn = conn;
```

then require that module in your code and you will be connected.

```
Connected!
```